# Why my fetch is not working, while I use Usestate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, javascript-objects

I want to make a component, which should have an input and button. The button should do some kind of work, I want it to show the information that I need to receive with fetch. In this case my code is not working, it shows a lot of [objects], however I want it to show the information from the base. if you can please help... : )

````
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
    const [User, setUser] = useState({num: ""})
    const [Open, setOpen] = useState(false)


    const users = () => {
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((json) => {
           document.write(json);
          });
        
      };


    return( <> 
        <input name="Num"  />
        <button  onClick={users}> Click Me for users </button>
        
    </>)

}

export default App ```
````

Comment: You need to set the state in the second then. Change `document.write(json);` to `setUser(json)`?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should almost never use document.write
2. Following is one of they ways you can solve your problem

```html
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [User, setUser] = useState({ num: "" });
  const [Open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const fetchAndSetUsers = () => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((users) => {
        setUsers(users);
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input name="Num" />
      <button onClick={fetchAndSetUsers}> Click Me for users </button>
      {users.map((user) => {
        return <div>{user.name}</div>;
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line of

```
document.write
```

to

```
setUsers(json)
```

You shouldn't manipulate UI directly in React using DOM methods since React uses Virtual DOM concept to update UI